# Does Java replace an object if it was the same name?

Tags: java, android

Does Java replace an object if it was the same name? This question comes to my mind daily.

**Example 1:** If I create an object 500 million times with the same object name, does Java create 500 million objects, or will it replace it and stay there in one object?

```
for (int x = 0; x < 500000000; x++) {
    TestObject testObject = new TestObject();
}
```

**Example 2:** Which way is better to avoid creating a new object every click?

```
//Using this way?
List < ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo > runningServiceInfoList = getRunningService();
activityMainBinding.activityMainConstraintLayout19.setOnClickListener(v - > {
    runningServiceInfoList.clear();
    runningServiceInfoList = getRunningService();
    if (...)
});

//Or this way?
activityMainBinding.activityMainConstraintLayout19.setOnClickListener(v - > {
    List < ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo > runningServiceInfoList = getRunningService();
    if (...)
});
```

Comment: "Does Java will create 500 million objects" It might create no objects at all, if escape analysis determines that it doesn't need to.

Comment: There is something that objects have in computing which is called "scope". The variable testObject is declared in the scope of the for loop, it means that once you're out of it, your variable will go straight to garbage collection. Also, Java code is compiled to byte code before being executed and when this happens, the JVM will perform many optimizations. In your specific example, the object testObject is not used so most probably the JVM wouldn't even create it at all.

Comment: About the scope (second example), always reduce the scope as much as you can. If you leave the variable `runningServiceInfoList` outside the lambda, it will survive during the whole lifetime of the function. If you actually need that variable to be there only inside the lambda, then declare it inside the lambda so that the JVM will figure out it can go to garbage collection (even though the optimizations I was mentioning above would still make it eligible to garbage collection even if you "forgot" to make it cleanable explicitly)

Comment: To conclude: most languages (including Java) have garbage collection. It means you almost never need to worry about memory because GC does that for you. At the same time, GC is a costly process (languages like C++ don't have GC, which makes them way faster than Java but leave to you the dirty job of cleaning the memory - and if you don't, you'll go quickly into memory leaks), so it's always suggested you help GC to identify potential candidates for garbage collection. Which translates into "always declare variables in the minimum scope possible".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Java will create 500 million objects

It might create no objects at all, if escape analysis determines that it doesn't need to, since it can just work with the field values on the heap instead.

Worrying about the number of objects created is worrying about things at the wrong level. Think about correctness first, speed later:

- If `TestObject` is immutable, there is no reason to create it in the loop: you can create it inside the loop if you want, or move it outside and reuse the instance.
- If `TestObject` is mutable, is there a risk that you will unintentionally leave state from previous iterations, which will corrupt the calculation in the current iteration? If so, unless creating a new `TestObject` is *really* expensive, just create new instances in the loop, because it's then more obviously correct. The JVM is really good at optimizing the life cycle of short-lived objects.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you're using the same name (in example 1), or even re-assigning to the same variable (in the first snippet of example 2) is inconsequential. A new object will be created, and the old object will be eligible for garbage collection.